# Error thrown before reaching Exception in Python

Tags: python, exception, filenotfounderror

I am creating a simple try - exception statement, where I want to create an exception when a certain file is missing or not found.

```
    try:
        pdfPath = "digitalPOTemplate.pdf"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("no template")
```

Essentially, I want the print statement to appear when there is no "digitalPOTemplate.pdf" found in the root directory. However, when I run this code, I get the FileNotFoundError, but the exception is not triggered. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Going only off of the code in your comment, no exception should be raised. Do you want to add `raise FileNotFoundError("error text")` under the `try` clause?

Comment: Just assigning the file name to a variable does not check whether the file exists, so you don't get an exception. Use [Path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) and then `raise` or get rid of the exception handling and just use an `if` to do something if the file does or does not exist.